# Define my own reader macro in clojure

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I would like to define my own reader macro in clojure:

```
(read-string "ßfoo")
=> (some_func :foo)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is possible to create tagged literals by having a reader map in `data_readers.clj` at the top of your classpath.

This must be in `data_readers.clj` at the top of your classpath (usually `src` directory).

```
{ß reader-demo.core/read-fn}
```

This goes into reader-demo.core

```
(defn some-func
  [arg]
  (str "some-func invoked with " arg))

(defn read-fn
  [arg]
  (-> arg
      keyword
      some-func))
```

Invoking

```
#ß foo
```

will return

```
"some-func invoked with :foo"
```

This technique is described here: [The reader: Tagged literals](http://clojure.org/reader#The%20Reader--Tagged%20Literals)

Notice that in practice you should namespace your tagged literals as all non-namespaced ones are reserved for Clojure itself.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Clojure doesn't allow to create user defined reader macros. This might/might not change in the future.