# Writing a Clojure #[...] Vector Function Macro

Tags: function, vector, clojure, macros

I want to write a Clojure vector macro form `#[...]` I can use like `#[(inc %1) %2]` that is equivalent to `(fn [a b] [(inc a) b])` or `#(vector (inc %1) %2)`.

Is this a special data reader, or can this be written with `defmacro`?

Comment: This is not possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/20677055 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/32453062.

Comment: No user reader macros in Clojure. Something similar looking could be done with tagged literals. Otherwise `#(do [(inc %1) %2])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for a laugh, I wrote up what is probably the closest you're going to come to a solution. It doesn't define a reader macro, but it does define a macro that almost allows for the syntax you're looking for.

I had to reinvent the wheel a bit to allow for `%` style implicit parameters since I couldn't get abusing `#()` to work:

```
(defn arg-list
  "Returns a lazy-seq of (%, %2, %3, ...) strings."
  ([] (arg-list 1))
  ([n] (lazy-seq
         (cons (str "%" (if (> n 1) n))
               (arg-list (inc n))))))

(defmacro lambda
  "Use as you would #(). (map (lambda (* % 2)) [1, 2, 3])"
  [& body]
  (let [arg-syms (->> (arg-list) (take 5) (mapv symbol))]
    `(fn [& ~arg-syms]
       ~@body)))
```

This defines a regular macro that mimics the `#()` reader macro. It evaluates to a variadic function that has the first 5 arguments in the list bound to "percentage" symbols. It allows for `%` style parameters:

```
(mapv (lambda (* % %2)) [1 2 3] [1 5 9])
[1 10 27]
```

Then, you can just use that to define a macro that almost does what you're looking for:

```
(defmacro vec-f [& elems]
  `(lambda (vec ~(vec elems))))
```

---

```
(mapv (vec-f (inc %) %2) [1 2 3] [1 5 9])
[[2 1] [3 5] [4 9]]
```

But I can't say that I recommend its use.

- It doesn't lend itself to readability.
- Instead of throwing `ArityException`s, the missed arguments will just default to `nil` via destructuring
- It only allows up to `%5`; although that's a hard-coded limit that can be increased. Using the current "var-arg method", I can't allow for an arbitrary number of parameters. Trying to realize an infinite list at compile time will obviously end in tears.

As a proof of concept though, it shows what you're after is *almost* possible.

You should just use

```
#(vector (inc %1) %2)
```

instead, or, as suggested in the comments

```
#(do [(inc %1) %2])
```